# Cordova works when run in the browser but not on device

Tags: cordova, angular

I have built an angular2 project in cordova. I've created a build using gulp and put the files to the cordova seed. It is working fine when it is run in the browser. But when i connect it to a device i am getting blank page.

Comment: Without any error message or code, no one can tell you. Try connecting to a debugger and see if there are JS console errors?

Comment: Echoing the others, we need to see code... are you waiting for the "deviceready" event and proceeding with your app launch after that also.  What happens when you try connecting Chrome debugger (for Android sim) or Safari (for iOS sim) and forcing a page refresh to reload your app, what errors appear in the console, any 404 errors loading dependent files in the network tab?

Comment: Please check my question here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40808179/cordova-app-not-loading-in-android-device-but-it-opens-in-browser?noredirect=1#comment68837176_40808179